# type derives based on string in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a `COLORS` object as the design spec.

```
export const COLORS = {
  background1: '#F9F9F9',
} as const
```

I need to transform them into a structure like this:

```
const colorStyle = { background1: { color: '#F9F9F9' } }
```

The type is like this:

```
type ColorStyle = {
  [key in keyof typeof COLORS]: {
    color: typeof COLORS[key]
  }
}
```

Works like a charm.

Now, consider I have many use cases like this, the only differences is the key: `color`, when it could be a value like `fontSize`, how to make a type to extract it?

I want to do something like this:

```
type DeriveStyle<Spec, Key extends string> = {
  [key in keyof Spec]: {
    [key: Key]: Spec[key]
  }
}
```

However, there is an error:

[image]

How to fix this, such that it will give me a type hint like this?

[image]

Which means, whatever I passed as the key, should be used in the final type as the property name, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the error by using the `in` operator, so that TS will know that the nested key should be of `Key` type with `K in Key` instead of `K: Key`:

```
type DeriveStyle<Spec, Key extends string> = {
  [K1 in keyof Spec]: {
    [K2 in Key]: Spec[K1]
  }
}

// i.e.
type ColorStyle = DeriveStyle<typeof COLORS, 'color'>;
```

I've added K1 & K2 to highlight different nesting level. You can see working example [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=55&pln=10&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wMIHkAyWBKAynALxwDeAUHHAEYCGCA1gOZQQCuyAJgIwBccAOQBiAGIBOSZKEAaSgF849VIhTpKlGAE8wwOABFgUAJYA3YIR0AbYAB5CehLLgBpYNrigYwHqvSmyCwAfKQU1HAA2q68cCbIcEweEABmcI7ACAC6glQ0NNEATHEJ7to56U7RvFkRCoqaOnpwGBDW0FbatmFGphadtnZNwKktuASELkJI7VBCwQDcQA).